# Rally issue with Track->Cross Release Tracking option

Tags: javascript, rally

We use Rally for Scrum.In Rally if you select Track>Cross Release Tracking,one issue is coming.That is when i am selecting one of the project and then its one release from the "Release drop down" it is not displaying any data.
Where as selecting releases of the same project whether single or in combination the data is getting displayed.
I tried to debug it and got few errors in sdk.js.In sdk.js there are 100 of functions in just a single line.That line starts as follows:

```
(function()
{
var b=window.Ext4||window.Ext;b.define("Deft.core.C
{
alternateClassName:["Deft.Class"],statics:
{
registerPreprocessor:function(d,g,c,e)
{
if(b.getVersion("extjs")&&b.getVersion("core").isLessThan("4.1.0"))
{
b.Class.registerPreprocessor(d,function(h,i,j)
{
return g.call(this,h,i,i,j)
}).setDefaultPreprocessorPosition(d,c,e)
}
else
{
b.Class.registerPreprocessor(d,function(i,j,h,k)
{
return g.call(this,i,j,h,k)
```

},

Do you have any idea how to resolve it.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code in proper way.. I tried it, But it is not in proper way. Look at this before asking questions [ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/ ]

Comment: Sounds like you're running into an issue with this Catalog app: https://help.rallydev.com/cross-workspace-release-status-app. It's possible that you're running a customized version of the app that's having problems. I'd recommend re-installing the app to see if that helps, as a first cut. Also - since this reports Release status across different workspaces, make sure you have permissions to access to all of the workspaces that are needed for reporting.

Comment: As mentioned by Kumar i have rewied my question.Also would like to know whether sdk.js is self generated or has been written and  is there there some way to breakup the code in sdk.js as it consists of so many functions in just one single line?

Answer (score 0):

That source looks like you are getting it from clicking "View Source" in your browser. That will probably not be the source you are hoping for if I am understanding you correctly the source for the App you want may be [here](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/legacy/CrossWsReleaseStatusMashup.html?source=c).

Please note, that specific App is pretty old and predates our first SDK. It may be challenging to change it.

Comment: I am getting the source by going to the options in Google chrome browser then selecting tools>developer tools then a sub window opens and then i get "html.sp?width=1...sEditable=true"in sub window and i am debugging this only, then getting error in "sdk.js" which is also in the same sub window.So,is this not the correct source which i am debugging?